# Change login screen background dark to transparent

Tags: linux, debian, login-screen, configure, gdm

I recently changed from a Windows user to Linux(debian 12) after 10yrs. I'm a beginner user and just saw some tutorials (not so user friendly), but I'm just loving the learning process. These are my pc specs: [image]

**My question is**: When I shutdown and boot up my system, the login screen shows a dark background
[image]

, but after logging in, the login screen seems to apply a transparency and blur effect like the one in the photo below. What you are seeing is actually my desktop wallpaper: [image]

Can I make this transparency and blur effect the default ? Any other more suggestions would be welcome as well.

Comment: What do you mean when you say your login screen is dark? Is it completely black, or darker than you want? You can take a picture using a camera. Your desktop background is a function of your user profile, and the computer does not load your profile until you login, which is probably why you see your background on the lock screen and not the login screen. Your profile is loaded when you're on the lock screen. I would suggest setting a LOGIN screen background and see if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Multiple guides on our sister sites: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/310923/how-to-customize-gnome-login-screen-in-debian and https://askubuntu.com/questions/202129/how-i-can-change-the-gdm-login-screen-wallpaper

Comment: Did you get a chance to review the links I provided yet?

Comment: @music2myear, I was able to change login screen something but I was unable to get transparency effect after booting . I'm not looking to change my login background screen but make it transparent which happens after logging in